# How to activate a button when something changes with Telerik RadGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, telerik, radgrid

I work with WebForms and Telerik.
On my site I have a RadGrid with a GridTemplateColumn.

```
<telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Blub">
                                <HeaderStyle Width="200px" />
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <div class="blubClass">
                                        <MyProject:OwnElement runat="server" />
                                    </div>
                                </ItemTemplate>
</telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

On my page I have a save button outside my table.

When a value in the table changes (EditMode="Batch") the save button should be enabled.
This does not work if I have a GridTemplateColumn.
If I use GridBoundColumn it works great.

This example from Telerik did not work for me

```
<telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Exhibition Title" UniqueName="exhibitionTitle">
   <EditItemTemplate>
      <asp:TextBox ID="txtExhibitionTitle" runat="server" 
                        Text='<%#Bind("exhibitionTitle")%>' />
 </EditItemTemplate>
 <ItemTemplate>
      <%#Eval("exhibitionTitle")%>
  </ItemTemplate>
</telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

Source => https://www.telerik.com/forums/update-fails-when-using-gridtemplatecolumn-a3e1ed9f7db7

Any idea how to enable the save button when I am in batch edit mode and the save button is outside the grid ?